# How to Send OTP with Sender Name in Firebase SMS Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to `android` development, I have using `firebase OTP` for my app registration process. It was works great. Now I saw several companies using their owns Sender Name with Images in it when sending OTP to customers. Their OTP number was just four digit only.

Company OTP:

[image: Image from Company OTP]

Firebase OTP:

[image: Image from my Firebase OTP]

I want to know how they send these OTP messages. What kind of OTP Service they are using. I want  my name as **Sender Name** instead of 57161678. How to achieve this. Is there any other OTP Service Available. I have searched StackOverflow  a lot but I couldn`t find any answer. Please help me with some solution.

Comment: Most probably they are not using firebase for mobile auth . They have their own auth system and their own sms gateway .

Comment: @SurajBahadur Yes I saw that. They say that we can't change the template nor sender name/number. Then how did these truecaller, byjus  are using their own names in their numbers and their OTP was just 4 digits. What Kind of Service they are using. I know that they are not using Firebase because the name can't be changed. Then what type of OTP Service they are using???

Comment: @Manohar, Yes I know that. I want to Know what auth system and gateway they are using. I have seen lots of OTP messages with their Company Name as a Sender Name in it. In 2021, its possible for all of us. .I just want to know what type of Service are they using to achieve this.

Comment: @BabyDoll You can search on google like third-party OTP service providers and you can get a bunch of companies who provide the services For example https://2factor.in/.  Also, the company screenshot that you have posted not using the firebase service.